# Deploy Scraping Scripts in python

Tags: python, selenium, deployment

Hello I have a selenium script in python which extract data with login on webpage. It take around 50 sec to execute and I want to deploy that script as an api. But API is getting timeout.
There we can also do one thing that we save that data in some google sheet using that script.

Please anyone can suggest how can i do this or any relevant content ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide us a screenshot of API timeout or logs? Showing Python code with requests will be also helpful (sorry for answering instead of commenting because I don't have enough reputation points)